# get some percentage of number of rows of a dataframe nestedly

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sas

I need to randomly select a % of dataframe rows and assign a value to new column, again in selected % of rows, I need to get another some % of random rows and apply a value to new added column.
As in below dataframe, I have added col1 and have set 50% of records to 'A' and next 50% to 'B'. When adding col2, I need to select first 40% of (50% of col1) and set value to 'aa' and next 60% of (50% of col1) to 'aaa'.

*I am not looking to take reference of added columns (like col1) and its values in (df.loc) as `df.loc(df['col1']=='A', ['col2']) = 'aa'`  to set value to col2, cause there will be multiple columns and their values to put as condition.*

[image]

**I am showing you the df without randomizing the data**

Below is the code I am using to randomly select a % of rows and assign some value to them.

```
import random

def cond_index(df, m, n, random):
    return (df[random] >= np.percentile(df[random], m)) & (df[random] <= np.percentile(df[random], n))

size = df.shape(0)
df['random_1'] = random.sample(range(size), size)
df.loc[cond_index(df, 'random_1', 0, 30),
       ['LC1', 'LC2', 'A1']
] = [200, 5000, 'ATH']
```

But this is just for 1 loop. What if I need to select 20% of 30% of records already selected and add values for them in a new column.

All this fuss is to implement a simple piece of code written in SAS into python.

```
Rannum = ranuni(0)*100; Rannum = round(Rannum,1);
Rannum1 = ranuni(0)*100; Rannum1 = round(Rannum1,1);
Rannum2 = ranuni(0)*100; Rannum2 = round(Rannum2,1);


if 0 <= Rannum <= 30 then do;
    L1 = 20;
    L2 = 50;
end;


if 31 <= Rannum1 <= 100 then do;

    A1 = 1;
    B1 = 2;

    if 0 <= Rannum2 <= 50 then do;
        C1 = 'c';
        D1 = 'd';
    end;
    
    if 51 <= Rannum2 <= 100 then do;
        C1 = 'c2';
        D1 = 'd2';
    end;

end;
```

*Please let me know if you need any further explanation on my question. Thanks in advance.*

Comment: Should the random percentage of rows be consecutive, or can it by spread across the entire dataframe (e.g., every other row, even if that wouldn't seem random).

Comment: doesn't matter, we just need random sets of records to be set with different values.

Comment: Oh, and how many "loops" can be there? That is, how many columns (two in the example) in total would be added, each one subdividing the previous division?

Comment: yes.... it can be any number of columns in 1 if else, and can be many nested if else, but for simplicity let's take 3. As you can see the sas code is very simple and easy to write conditions. The goal is to achieve the same in python.

Comment: Ok. What I don't understand: is there any importance to the existing columns "A" and "B"? Also, what is the code about: there are calls to `np.percentile`, and some mention of (columns?) `['LC1', 'LC2', 'A1']`, but nothing of that all makes sense to the question you are asking. Your actual question seems to basically be: how do I generate an n-level (uneven) binary tree (along the rows of a Pandas dataframe)?

Comment: And what are the new values based on? Are these given, or somehow generated? Since the apparent logic like "A -> aa/aaa" doesn't really extend well to higher levels (the third column could contain numbers, but what a potential fourth column?)

Comment: Also: are the "division percentages" given, or can those also be random? In your example, it's 50%/50%, then 40%/60%. Would these be set by a user (only one number is needed for each level, obviously; unless you want a non-binary division), or can these be random as well?

Comment: So RANDOM2 is nested inside of RANDOM1.  But RANDOM is independent of the other two.

Comment: The SAS code you provide does not assign values to all of the target variables in all cases.  What values do you want them to be?  Why is the SAS code not just use the TABLE distribution of the RAND() function to generate three variables with jtwo categories each?  `group0 = rand('table',.3);
group1 = rand('table',.3);
group2 = rand('table',.5);`

Comment: The goal here is to condition the already present data by assigning values to different columns and rows (randomly but percentage-wise), so that I can make different probable scenarios. I will run my model on top of this data to check whether it passes all conditions. Also I need to make this conditioning process easy and simple so that building for multiple scenarios don't look messy. @9769953

Comment: all columns like A and B or even col1 or col2 are just there in my pre-existing dataframe, it's a raw data. I am just changing the values of a few columns (in nested manner) and rows (percentage-wise). The percentage needs to be dynamic, let's say I divided col1 in 30% and 70% and set two different values for them. Now for 80% of col1 I need to set a value for col2 and rest 20% any other value.

Comment: That doesn't answer my questions: what's the relevancy of the current code to your example dataframe, since they don't seem to align; what are the values in the new columns based on (the A;aa/aaa, B;bb/bbb parts); is "dynamic" random, or assigned by a user?

Comment: @9769953 these values are assigned by users.